# SDK for SCIM Implementation

Tags: rest, identity, scim

I have developed a REST based webservice to manage user identities on a custom identity store. The API supports basic operations such as create user, update user and view user. I want to make the API SCIM compliant and provide SCIM endpoint URLs for user operations. The System for Cross-domain Identity Management (SCIM) documentation mainly talks about the specification but doesn't provide the details to create a SCIM compliant service. Is there any SDK available to create a SCIM service.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Java? If so, have you considered using the UnboundID SCIM SDK? See https://github.com/UnboundID/scim2

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of resources: http://www.simplecloud.info/#Resources

The page also contains a lot of documentation and useful links wrt SCIM.